# shell test whether multiple lines string contains specified pattern in last line

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, quoting, test

I want to determine whether a multi-line string ends with a line containing specified pattern.

These code failed, it doesn't match.

```
s=`echo hello && echo world && echo OK`
[[ "$s" =~ 'OK$' ]] && echo match
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `bash` 3.2 or above and if the compatibility to 3.1 is not enabled (with the `compat31` option or `BASH_COMPAT=3.1`), quoting regular expression operators (not only with `\` but with any of the `bash` quoting operators (`'...'`, `"..."`, `$'...'`, `$"..."`)) removes their special meaning.

```
[[ $var =~ 'OK$' ]]
```

matches only in strings that contain `OK$` literally (that `$` matches a literal `$`)

```
[[ $var =~ OK$ ]]
```

matches on strings that end in `OK` (that `$` is the RE operator that matches at the end of the string).

That also applies to regexps stored in variables or the result of some substitution.

```
[[ $var =~ $regexp ]]   # $var matches $regexp
[[ $var =~ "$string" ]] # $var contains $string
```

Note that it can become awkward because there are some characters that you need to quote for the shell syntax (like blanks, `<`, `>`, `&`, parenthesis when not matched). For instance, if you want to match against the `.{3} <> [)}]&` regexp (3 characters followed by a `" <> "`, either a `)` or `}` and a `&`), you need something like:

```
[[ $var =~ .{3}" <> "[}\)]\& ]]
```

If in doubt about which characters need quoting, [you can always use a temporary variable](/q/382054). That also means it will make the code compatible to `bash31`, `zsh` or `ksh93`:

```
pattern='.{3} <> [})]&'
[[ $var =~ $pattern ]] # remember *not* to quote $pattern here
```

That's also the only way (short of using the `compat31` option (or `BASH_COMPAT=3.1`)) you can make use of the non-POSIX extended operators of your system's regexps.

For instance, for `\<` to be treated as the word boundary which it is in many regexp engines, you need:

```
pattern='\<word\>'
[[ $var =~ $pattern ]]
```

Doing:

```
[[ $var =~ \<word\> ]]
```

won't work as `bash` treats those `\` as shell quoting operators and strip them before passing `<word>` to the regexp library.

Note that it's a lot worse in ksh93 where:

```
[[ $var =~ "x.*$" ]]
```

for instance will match on `whatever-xa*` but not `whatever-xfoo`. The quoting above removes the special meaning to `*`, but not to `.` nor `$`.

The `zsh` behaviour is simpler: quoting doesn't change the meaning of regexp operators there (like in bash31) which makes for a more predictable behaviour (it can also use PCRE regexps instead of ERE (with `set -o rematchpcre`)).

`yash` doesn't have a `[[...]]` construct, but its `[` builtin has a `=~` operator (also in `zsh`). And of course, `[` being a normal command, quoting can't affect the way regexp operators are interpreted.

---

Also note that strictly speaking, your `$s` doesn't contain 3 lines, but 2 full lines followed by an unterminated line. It contains `hello\nworld\nOK`. In the `OK$` extended regular expression, the `$` operator would only match at the end of the *string*.

In a 3-full-lines *string*, like `hello\nworld\nOK\n` (which you wouldn't be able to obtain with command substitution as command substitution strips *all* trailing newline characters), the `$` would match after the `\n`, so `OK$` wouldn't match on it.

With `zsh -o pcrematch` however, the `$` matches both at the end of the string and before the newline at the end of the string if there's one as it doesn't pass the `PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY` flag to `pcre_compile`. [That could be seen as a bad idea as generally, variables in shells do not contain a trailing newline character, and when they do, we generally want them considered as data](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg01708.html).

Answer (score 3):

At least in `bash`, quoting the RHS forces it to be treated as a string comparison

```
$ s=$(printf 'hello\nworld\nOK\n')
$ echo "$s"
hello
world
OK
$ [[ "$s" =~ OK$ ]] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
match
```

whereas

```
$ s=$(printf 'hello\nworld\nOK$\n')
$ echo "$s"
hello
world
OK$
$ [[ "$s" =~ 'OK$' ]] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
match
```

Comment: Wow, Such a quirk! I do use `bash`.

Comment: The second case should output "no match".

Answer (score 1):

Little known fact: `case` does this, too.

```
case "$(printf 'hello\nworld\nOK\n')" in
  *$'\nOK') echo "match";;
  *) echo "no match";;
esac
```

The `$'...'` "C-style" string is a Bash extension (which provides a context where backslash escape codes like `\n` are available in shell strings), but for portabiity, you can say

```
*"
OK") echo "match";;
```

to get a completely POSIX-compatible shell script.

The patterns available in a `case` statement are shell glob patterns, not proper regular expressions, though.